# Trouble reading tif images using image_read in Magick package

Tags: r, tiff, magick-r-package

I am trying to read a .tif image from a local directory using the image_read command in the Magick package. My code results in the following error:

```
"Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth, strip) : 
  Magick: Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored. `TIFFFetchNormalTag' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/910"
```

I am using Magick version 1.6 in R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18),in OS X 10.10.5

An identical file in jpeg format in the same folder opens fine. A few other posts mention difficulty with .tif files, but none seemed to offer a solution for my specific issue.

```
myimage <- image_read("/Users/myusername/Desktop/test/3.tif")
```

Comment: Can you share the image?